# Content Type admin-side UI

Tags: 7, routes, nodes

I have a custom content type which has grown in fields count and all that UI hints and stuff. It now takes about 4-5 screens to scroll. I was wondering if anyone knows of a module/way that allows to re-organize the Add Content UI form into sections. For instance - I would like to have all head data (title, teaser text, description) on a separate tab, all taxonomy qualifiers on another one, all images and uploads on yet another one, etc.

I think such a re-organized way will be much more friendly for the client to fill up with info and to maintain as well.

Anyone?
Artur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Multistep](http://drupal.org/project/multistep) module. Although it is under development for Drupal 7.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that's good to know. I don't mind the dev status if the module is actively maintained, which seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're content with keeping the form as a single page and just want to be able to segment out the UI of what's on that screen a bit you might be able to use [Field group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) as well.

(So the whole thing could be a single page but part broken out into horizontal/vertical tabs, accordions, etc.)

Comment: Yep, thanks for your answer. Since the time I asked the question, I already did quite a progress in Drupal and now know about Field Group. That's what I would have today marked as an answer. However I have a problem where my content type does not display fieldsets correctly, and hell know whether Field Group has played a role in that bogus display.